# What would happen if we changed Earth's orbit?

Tags: orbit

If one day we have enough technology to push the Earth away a bit further from the sun to reduce global warming, is it true that it will start to distort the orbits of Mars and Venus, giving them a larger eccentricity and finally colliding with sun or each other?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is purely hypothetical. We do not have, nor can conceivably ever obtain the technology to change the orbit of a planet significantly.

Comment: I regard this more as a q about relative gravitational attraction with a fairly simple answer: although all planets exert gravitational force on each other, the gravity generated by Earth on Venus and Mars is fairly small, and moving the Earth's orbit slightly will have only a minimal impact on Venus' and Mars' orbits. And, if global warming is occurring (not everyone agrees) and we have that level of technology, we probably have better less energy intensive solutions than moving the planet. I disagree with @JamesKilfiger though... using asteroids and stuff we MIGHT be able to do it one day.

Comment: Note to those who voted to migrate: The question has been closed on Worldbuilding (see [my comment](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39254/what-would-happen-if-we-changed-earths-orbit#comment110576_39254)) to the author for reasons I gave there. Please refrain from migrating What-If questions to Worldbuilding if they aren't actually about worldbuilding. Thanks.

Comment: Relevant meta question: http://meta.astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/296/thought-experiments

Comment: **To those who have voted to reopen:** this question is not on topic just because it got closed on Worldbuilding. It is not merely off topic here because of its speculative nature. It is not about Astronomy; it is about geoengineering of Earth. Its effects on other planets brush with the field of celestial mechanics, but the engineered nature of the enterprise makes it more like orbital mechanics (space exploration) than Astronomy which is primarily concerned with the observation of the natural processes.